# Calling Function in Another Workbook Causes Crash or Automation Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to copy a sheet (called Copy) from the source (called Book1.xlsm) to copy a sheet to the target workbook (called Book2.xlsb). Before I do the copy, I call a macro in the target (Book2.xlsb) to make certain it's an older version.

Excel crashes or gives an Automation Error Exception Occurred or just a crash when the target workbook is closed (with both saving or not saving).

When I do this from a blank xlsm or xlsb, there is no crash. I use any of 10 real world spreadsheets (from 2MB up to 34MB xlsb), and it happens all the time.

I've spent days trying to make the minimal viable example crash with a smaller spreadsheet as a target with no luck.

The target spreadsheets contain no vba code (just formulas) except for the module that gets imported from the source.

My example has Button1 to make a single copy. 1 field exists for version number (Cell A2).

I am left with the impression that calling code in another workbook is just a bad idea or I'm missing something fundamental. If the call to the target worksheet is not made, everything runs fine.

Main Question: Is running code from another workbook just a bad idea or am I missing something?

Before saving I've tried:

```
Application.Calculate
Do Until (Application.CalculationState = xlDone) And _
         (Application.Workbooks.Count <> 1) And _
         (Application.VBE.VBProjects.Count 
  DoEvents
Loop
TmpTgtWorkbook.Close False
Set TmpTgtWorkbook = Nothing
```

Before opening, I always make certain only the source workbook is open.

```
Option Explicit
Function GetVersion(aWorkbook As Workbook) As Double
  Dim TmpSheet As Worksheet

  GetVersion = 0

  On Error Resume Next
  Set TmpSheet = aWorkbook.Sheets("Copy")
  On Error GoTo 0

  If TmpSheet Is Nothing Then
    Exit Function
  End If

  GetVersion = CDbl(TmpSheet.Range("B1"))
End Function
Sub CopyToBook2()
  Dim TmpTgtWorkbook As Workbook
  Dim TmpSrcVersion As Double
  Dim TmpTgtVersion As Double
  Const kWorkbookStr = "Book2.xlsb"

  TmpSrcVersion = GetVersion(ThisWorkbook)

  ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Export "C:\Temp\Module1"

  Set TmpTgtWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + kWorkbookStr)

  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
  'Run the GetVersion Function from the Opened Workbook.
  'Removing this line takes away crashes.
  TmpTgtVersion = Application.Run(kWorkbookStr + "!GetVersion", TmpTgtWorkbook)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    TmpTgtVersion = 0
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  If TmpSrcVersion > TmpTgtVersion Then
    On Error Resume Next
    TmpTgtWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove TmpTgtWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TmpTgtWorkbook.Sheets("Copy").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    TmpTgtWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\Temp\Module1"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Copy").Copy TmpTgtWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    TmpTgtWorkbook.ChangeLink ThisWorkbook.Name, TmpTgtWorkbook.Name, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    TmpTgtWorkbook.Close True
  Else
    TmpTgtWorkbook.Close False
  End If
End Sub
```

Automation Error Exception Occurred and then a crash or just a crash.

Also, you need to run the code by clicking Button1 2x or more to first copy the module to the target.

Comment: why not run the script from your source workbook without going through the trouble of exporting it?

Comment: Because the Copy tab needs to put the functionality into the target workbook. It's adds functionality to already existing workbooks. If I run it from the source, it returns the Source workbook's version when I want the Target workbook's version. If the cell with the version number ever changes location, need to get the Target version from the code that matches the Target version location. I was planning on using this to version modules without worksheets (to make certain that older modules do not copy over newer versions). In that case, was hoping to just call GetModuleVersionXXX (XXX=Module).

Comment: you can create a hidden sheet for the version and put the version number on cell A1 and then read it from the source workbook

Comment: That would work. I would need to have 2 columns with the Module Description and then the version number. I am building a base pattern to support multiple automation templates for different existing spreadsheets. Still that's a really good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Abdes Sabor's workaround. Thanks for that.

Also, considering a small version system for the future which code modules have the CodeModuleName_Major_Minor version format.

My Main Question: Is running code from another workbook just a bad idea or am I missing something?

Unfortunately, all evidence point to Yes. Running a function using `Application.Run` in another worksheet seems to be bad and potentially corrupts spreadsheets.